# Ant XSLT task vs. Java task

Tags: java, ant, xslt

I've inherited a project which contains an ant build file.  We are in the process of upgrading libraries, and when we did our **ancient** XSLT translator began flaking out.  I've attempted to replace the calls with ant's XSLT task, however it throws some errors in our translators (xalan at the command line throws no such error).

Is there a way to use the fileset in combination with a java task?  It would sure beat having to repeat the majority of the call umpteen times.  The only thing I can really think of is passing a variable to a sub-ant task, but perhaps there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this carefully in the preamble to the XSLT task:

> Note: If you are using JDK 1.4 or
>   higher, this task does not require
>   external libraries not supplied in the
>   Apache Ant distribution. However,
>   often the built in XSL engine is not
>   as up to date as a fresh download, so
>   an update is still highly recommended
>   in particular since the built-in XSLT
>   processors of Java 5 (and to a certain
>   extent Java 6) are known to have
>   serious issues. See Library
>   Dependencies for more information.

If you are running the latest version of Ant, the XSLT task has a `classpath/classpathref` parameters that supposedly are used to locate the XSLT processor.

Because our project started before 1.8 was released, we've used the "usual" Ant way of supplying such libraries: either by copying them to the ant's `lib` dir or by supplying `-lib` switch for the `ant` call.

Note, for Xalan to work properly you need to add both `xalan-X.X.X.jar` and `xalan-serializer-X.X.X.jar` to the classpath.

Comment: I hadn't set ANT_HOME in eclipse, so it was using the version which was built in, which was 1.7.1.  I had read that portion, but was skipping it due to "thinking" I had set it to properly utilize 1.8.2